# Print webbrowser content as landscape

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, printing, webbrowser-control

I need to print document from WebBrowser control as landscape (without showing PrintPreview and changing default printer page orientation).

I've tried:

1. TemplatePrinter
   Here's my template template.html:

   ```
   <HTML XMLNS:IE>
   <HEAD>
   <?IMPORT NAMESPACE="IE" IMPLEMENTATION="#default">
   <TITLE>Landscape</TITLE>
   </HEAD>
   <BODY>
   <IE:TEMPLATEPRINTER id="Printer"/>
   <SCRIPT Language="JavaScript">
   Printer.orientation="landscape";
   </SCRIPT>
   </BODY>
   </HTML>
   ```

   And I try to use it:

   ```
   mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = wbReport.Document.DomDocument as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2;
   doc.execCommand("print", false, "template.tpl");
   ```
2. Create reg key "orientation" with value "2" in HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\PageSetup
3. Add style like:

   ```
   <style type="text/css" media="print">
   @page
   {
    size: landscape;
    margin: 2cm;
   }
   </style>
   ```

But I still print my html as portrait.
Maybe there is better solution to print html as landscape or I have some mistakes when using TemplatePrinter?

Comment: Surely it's not as simple as a spelling error.  But I must point out you have one in your code or need to edit the question to reflect the correct spelling.  In #1 you have "TemplatePrinter Here's my template template.`html`:" and then when you USE it you have "doc.execCommand("print", false, "template.`tpl`");"  Change the tpl to html?

Comment: have you found a solution to this question yet?  Maybe share what the template html looks like (complete) to make it print landscape?

Answer (score 4):

After messing around with the registry, attempting to use print templates in IE and various other methods (none of which worked) i've produced a somewhat hacky workaround.

I've extended the WebBrowser control and created a new print preview method inside which I have methods to pass the ALT+L key combination to enable landscape view:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace YourProjectNamespace
{
    class ExWebBrowser : WebBrowser
    {
        void setLandscapeTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendKeys.SendWait("%L");
            this.ProcessDialogKey(Keys.Alt & Keys.L);
            SendKeys.Flush();
        }

        public void _ShowPrintPreviewDialog()
        {
            this.ShowPrintPreviewDialog();
            this.Focus();

            Timer setLandscapeTimer = new Timer();
            setLandscapeTimer.Interval = 500;
            setLandscapeTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(setLandscapeTimer_Tick);
            setLandscapeTimer.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

All you need to do is simply instantiate the object, load a document as with the standard WebBrowser and call _ShowPrintPreviewDialog.

Note you may want to stop the timer once the landscape view has been set.

HTH somebody with the same issue.